# How to add aac and libx264 to FFmpeg installation?

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg

I've already installed FFmpeg according to the [ffmpeg Ubuntu compile guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

I can't use aac audio encoding and libx264, which I need.

How do I install FFmpeg so that all the option below are enabled in the installation? Do I need to uninstall FFmpeg and start over again, or can I just add to what has already been installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this on a regular basis since I like to use ffmpeg's bleeding edge features now and then.

For `libfdk-aac` and `libx264`, you want to install the respective development packages:

```
sudo apt install libfdk-aac-dev libx264-dev
```

Then I configure ffmpeg like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg-$(cat RELEASE) --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-gnutls --disable-librtmp --disable-libopencv --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --arch=amd64 --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-doc --extra-cflags=--static --extra-libs="-ldl" --disable-outdev=alsa --disable-outdev=oss --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=sndio --disable-indev=alsa --disable-indev=oss --disable-indev=sndio --disable-indev=jack
```

As you see, I explicitly enable libx264 and fdk-aac and I disable a lot of features I don't need. Your mileage may vary, of course. The fancy part is `--prefix=/opt/ffmpeg-$(cat RELEASE) --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-doc --extra-cflags=--static --extra-libs="-ldl"`, which gives you a static compile. `make install` will put it into `opt`, so it does not conflict with the ffmpeg version provided by the package manager.

I do not actually execute `make install`, though. Instead I use

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgname="ffmpeg-$(cat RELEASE)" --pkgversion="$(cat RELEASE)~git$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" --backup=no --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default
```

to produce a Debian package I can uninstall without hassle.

In case this information becomes obsolete, I probably update the corresponding [post](https://ssl.hehoe.de/artikel/blog/ffmpeg-fur-avxsynth-oder-ultrastar-deluxe-kompilieren.html) in my personal blog.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reliable guide to installing libx264. I just used it and it worked.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20FFmpeg%20with%20libx264%20%28x264,%20H.264%29

Comment: This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [do not post an answer which is just a link to another site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). At least summarize the content in your post. See [How to Answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more tips on writing answers.

Comment: 404 not found, update the link